# Is it possible to do Seamless RDP connection using node-rdpjs?

Tags: node.js, windows, rdp, mstsc

Hi I have tried to search on google about how I can seamlessly connect to windows machine through RDP using [node-rdpjs](https://github.com/citronneur/node-rdpjs) but haven't got any hint.

Here is scenario for User :

- should be able to connect to multiple software
- should be same user name
- should same machine

I have seen this video tutorial about who actually it is done in windows.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g30RWJoqONI

Any help / hint is appreciated.

Thank you